# Rich Text Editor - Apply CSS class around <tr> html tag

Tags: sxa, richtext-editor, css

I have selected the complete row of the table, Then I have selected a class that changes the background color of the table row.

[image: Class selection]

The background color is not applying to the selected table row, because RTE added header class inside the table data cell.

**Excepted**

```
 <tr class="header">
        <td>&nbsp;test</td>
        <td>&nbsp;test</td>
        <td>&nbsp;tesy</td>
 </tr>
```

**Result**

```
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;t
        <div class="header">est</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="header">&nbsp;test</div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="header">&nbsp;tesy</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Is there any way to achieve the above-expected result in `Sitecore RTE`?

Comment: try removing `class="header"` and check, i think you will need to wrap the whole `tr` into something else

Comment: i need to add **header** class to table row, if i use above paragraph classes (refer above image), it is adding classes to tables data cell. Is there any way to add classes to table row in RTE?

Comment: instead of `<tr class="header">` use `th` instead and  style it. this way you wont have markup issues.

Comment: You could potentially use a snippet if that would make sense.  That way you have control over the html that gets spat out.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new CSS class in the Rich Text Editor dropdown and apply it to the selected row table.

There are two steps to add CSS class in RTE:

1. Add  element in`Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ToolsFile.xml` file.
2. Now add the definition of that CSS class (eg. `arrowlink`) in `Website\default.css` file.

You can see newly added `arrowlink` CSS class in rich text editor dropdown. And apply this class wherever you want.